Tense that would include past, present and the future?
If I say "I was athletic", It means it was in the past.
If I say "I have been athletic", it means I was in the past and I remain athletic today.
Is there any way to say "I was, I am and I will be athletic" using some tense or grammatical construct?

The second example is incorrect. It can mean "... but I am not athletic today".

Would you say then "I have always been athletic" is the correct way?

I am an athletic person implies that you were, and will be athletic too.

The 'implies' part is not specific enough for me)

The present tense here is a continuum. Obviously, not just for today unless it's a fantasy.

Please help me to understand. My understanding was that when you use present prefect  by itself implies "was AND still is". And in your example it is not the case: The second example is incorrect. It can mean "... but I am not athletic today". Why?

Is there any language where you can say "I was, I am and I will be athletic" explicitly without a conjunction?

Not that I know of

Example 2 again: saying "I have been athletic" suggests it wasn't your usual state of fitness.

@Vaskaelgato I'm a bit confused as to why you'd expect there to be one in English.

"...using some tense or grammatical construct." By using always. "I have always been athletic". But nobody can predict the future.

@alphabet because russian language for example does not even have present perfect. So the existence of present perfect made me think maybe there is some analog for the future tense

...or by using an adjective: "I am a seasoned athlete", etc.

I have worked places the time in the past. Could be present, too. I have been working on places the time in the past and present, continually but not necessarily continuously.

If you say "I am athletic" without any qualification, it normally describes yourself in general, not at any particular time. Just like saying "I am American" or "I am white/black/...".

If you wanted to be more specific you would say something like "I am now athletic".

If you want to emphasize the enduring nature, you have to say "I have been, and always will be, athletic." There's no single tense that encompasses this.

'I remain athletic.'

Can an infant be athletic? Can you claim in the future the person will always be athletic? I've never seen a river long enough that doesn't contain a bend. Is athletic defined prior to birth and after death?

@Vaskaelgato The issue is that, since the present perfect doesn't generally mean "was and still is," this question is based on a faulty premise.

I think we can work out what the question is asking regardless of the mistake about the meaning of the present perfect (but the OP should still correct it). The main issue is that there's no answer other than stuff like "I am eternally athletic."

“I have always been athletic” works for past and present, and implies the future—the continuation of the present condition—unless followed by a phrase contradicting that situation.

This answer comes from my experience as a speaker of the American English dialect in the Philadelphia area. In this part of the country for sure, and I believe elsewhere, at least in the demimonde I inhabited for almost two decades as father of athletic sons on nationally ranked soccer teams who traveled to other states to play, "He's athletic" doesn't mean "You'll find him most days in the gym or outdoors getting exercise" but when used predicatively in the bare form, it refers to innate physical qualities, a person's "physical coordination" (large motor and hand-eye). That form is not a statement about  how "fit" or "in shape" he happens to be at any given moment. If we say, simply, "He's athletic" we mean "He's a born athlete" and the implication is that he would be good at any sport.
Merriam-Webster† comes very close to presenting that meaning:

active or gifted in sports, games, or exercises [my emphasis]

The word "gifted" is another way of saying "having innate traits", though that definition is rather telescoped and it should be teased out into two separate definitions: "gifted in exercises"?
And whether you happen to use the adjective that way or not is irrelevant. It can be used that way, and for many speakers it does have that meaning (having superior innate physical coordination) and this answer is  about the simple present used with the adjective "athletic" (per the question) in a manner that does not confine the utterance to the present because it expresses a "general truth". This answer evolved into an answer about this meaning of the adjective "athletic" because of the objections raised by a native speaker of Italian who objected to the comparison I made to genetic traits. "PITA" is right.
With the simple present and that bare predicate form,  "He's athletic", we are making a statement that was true, is true, and will continue to be true, even as one grows older into middle age and beyond. In this bare predicate form it's rather like saying "He's fair-skinned" or "He's blue-eyed" because we'e talking about something innate.  Thus, we would naturally (subconsciously) avoid saying "He was athletic" in conversation, though it might fly in a narrative told in the third person past. For example, that bare predicate construction is not what we would  choose when speaking of someone we see in the crowd at a game,  an old man walking hunched over with a cane, a man who in his youth had a reputation locally for being a great athlete, someone who had won "All State" honors on his high school team or "All American" honors in college. We would not say "He was athletic" but "He was once a great athlete".
Mari-Lou asks, in a comment below, "Are you saying that 'He was athletic' or 'She used to be athletic' are false statements?" and in doing so she is missing the central point that this form, as we use it, is referring to innate qualities of motor coordination and hand-eye coordination. I don't know what she has in mind when she says "He is athletic".  Is she thinking of his physique? His lifestyle? Does he spend a lot of time in the gym or running marathons? She brings up the phrase "the sporty type", so I think she may have lifestyle or physical appearance in mind.
P.S. And my answer is given in the context of the question, which is asking about a tense that can refer to past, present, and future, which the simple present in bare predicative form can, as it makes a statement that is not confined to the present but is a "truth" that was true yesterday, is true today, and will be true tomorrow. "Lemons are tart".  So, to the downvoters, I say, offer an explanation.
†“Athletic.” Merriam-Webster.com Dictionary, Merriam-Webster, https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/athletic. Accessed 29 Jun. 2024.

I should have said this earlier but I said, who needs to hear from a PITA such as myself? A person can stop being athletic at any time in the future. This is different from having blue eyes, and fair skin, traits which will (all things taken in consideration) persist until their death. Despite that, I upvoted because using the present tense e.g. "I am sporty" does imply past, present and future (although the latter not etched in stone).

@Mari-LouA I don't think you  fully understand how the word is used.  It refers to a person's innate physical coordination, not to their level of training or how "fit" or "in shape" they happen to be at any given moment.  "I am sporty" isn't idiomatic in AmE, in the sense that nobody says it.

And by "it" in my second sentence I mean the statement  "I'm athletic" or "He's |she's athletic".

It should have been "I'm (the) sporty (type)” I'm pretty sure that someone says that, with or without the words in brackets. I retracted the upvote btw because if that athletic person decides one day to start eating junk food, get into heavy drugs, alcohol and/or stops training, their athletic body will sooner rather than later suffer and become heavy, slower and less responsive.

@Mari-LouA You're not understanding how the word "athletic" is used. It doesn't mean "fit" or "in shape" in this predicative usage. Rather it means to possess a significantly better than average degree of innate physical coordination.  As for "the sporty type", that is a horse of a different color and hardly the same as "I am sporty". "The sporty type" is said of women, at least in the US.  We wouldn't say that a boy who is good at any sport he plays is "the sporty type". https://www.google.com/search?q=%22the%20sporty%20type%22&tbm=bks&tbs=cdr:1,cd_min:1939,cd_max:2010&lr=lang_en

Are you suggesting "He was athletic" or “She used to be athletic" are false statements? Would it only apply to the elderly?  You're the one who's arguing that being athletic is a semi-permanent condition akin to someone having blue eyes or being fair skinned.

@Mari-LouA  Your asking about the truth/falsehood of the formulation shows you are still not approaching this question from the point of view of idiomatic usage. "He used to be athletic" is not idiomatic in American English, because, in AmE, to be athletic is, as I have now said repeatedly, is a reference to superior innate physical coordination, which is not the same thing as being an athlete.  "He used to be an athlete" is the idiomatic formulation if you want to say a person played one or more sports when younger, such as being on the tennis team or the basketball team in college.

"To look at him now, all hunched over and walking with a cane, you'd never know he was a star athlete in college."

There's so many thousands of hits for "once athletic"!

@Araucaria-Him .   "He is athletic" and "He was once athletic"  can be using "athletic" in different ways. The first can refer (in AmE) to superior innate coordination (he's a "born athlete")  and the latter can mean "He was once fit and played one or more sports".   I might well say "He was once athletic" but I wouldn't say "He was athletic" since the bare predicate form "He is athletic" in my dialect means "He is a born athlete" and "He was a born athlete" is jarring semantically.

I think you need prefatory remarks explaining that what you say refers to a North American dialect, because it certainly not true of British English,  fr example!

@Araucaria-Him I've added the recommended disclaimer. Didn't expect to meet up with such literal-minded fact-content objections of the sort Mari-Lou was raising. I was talking  not about grammaticality and the adjective "athletic" in isolation but about the nuance of the simple predicate form "He's athletic".

@Mari-LouA  What do you mean when you say "He is athletic" ?  What idea would you be expressing there?
